# Metta's Intensity and Concentration

Tags: meditation-metta

I noticed that in my meditation on compassion, the beginning is consistently potent (i.e. tears, strong feeling) and the ending is usually less apt (i.e. body agitation, distraction).

**Would the emotional intensity of such a meditation depend highly on *concentration*?** Or, perhaps, would some other aspect explain this, e.g. becoming saturated emotionally early in the meditation?

Answer (score 1):

**I noticed that in my meditation on compassion, the beginning is consistently potent (i.e. tears, strong feeling) and the ending is usually less apt (i.e. body agitation, distraction).**

Most likely what is happening is when you think about different people

- your perception of them
- past incidents
- their situations

Stir up emotions.

**Would the emotional intensity of such a meditation depend highly on concentration? Or, perhaps, would some other aspect explain this, e.g. becoming saturated emotionally early in the meditation?**

Emotional intensity most likely goes down with meditations as your concentration increases your mind becomes stable.

Comment: So would a more advanced type of metta produce less emotions?

Comment: I believe so. See when you do not distinguish among different groups and being reacting with like and dislike then you will be less emotional. It is this reaction which makes you emotional.